# Ruby on rails, building a simple portfolio page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So I do freelance iPhone app development, and I need to a build a small website showing my company;s name and the apps I already deployed in apple app store, plus some images of my previous clients. 
I started playing with ruby on rails, and setup a skeleton app on heroku, its live and works.

My problem is I don't know how to create a lot of things in Web, like scrolling left to right, 
or adding a band that has icons. I don't know what should be the next thing to learn? should I readup on html and css? or is this a RoR functionality?
Anyone can guide me in the direction of a sample protfolio website in RoR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I'd leave Rails out of this equation altogether until you have HTML and CSS nailed down - you're going to add in a large layer of unneeded complexity if you try and start with a server-side framework like Rails before you understand the basics of building web pages.

I believe that http://net.tutsplus.com has free beginning HTML and CSS courses that should be more than enough to get you up to speed.

Comment: Thats what I am realizing, people have recommended a plugin called Jekyll, but although I am not a ruby expert, I get the feeling that I will end up building a sport scar when all I need is a scooter.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails is just the framework for the site. The flashy stuff you see on websites comes from javascript, css, html, etc. If you have the website functioning properly and are now looking to create the flashy pages to show off your apps, I'd suggest getting into javascript and css.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your application is a collection of static HTML/Web pages which has some data(text, images).
So I guess you really don't need a scripting language or framework to develop your site.
Having grip on HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JQuery will do everything up to my knowledge.